# Use subplots for pie char and bar char pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot, figure

I'm trying to show two graphs next to each other. pie char and bar char.
my code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig , ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 2)
df['column'].value_counts().plot.pie()
df['column'].value_counts().plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

this is the output:

[image]

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the subplots to the plot commands:

```
fig , ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 2)

df['column'].value_counts().plot.pie(ax=ax[0])
df['column'].value_counts().plot.bar(ax=ax[1])

plt.show()
```